# How to send jquery request from another pc of same computer network

Tags: jquery

I have two pc (windows 7) running on the same network (network Server). I have installed zpanel (Apache, Mysql & Control Panel) in my pc. I have different webpages which send jquery request to another pages (suppose pageA.php is requesting jquery request to pageB.php) and receive response data. It works well on my computer. But If I access the same page (pageA.php) from another pc in the same network, that page could not send/receive to pageB.php. It is noted that Apache, mysql is intalled on my pc. I assume, another pc of same network considering my pc as separate domain. So the jquery request is not executing for cross domain issue.

How to resolve this issue, i.e pageA can send request to pageB and receive response by jquery thereafter from both my pc and another pc in the same network?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the three tire architecture in your application. 
So that the server part will be separated from your local machine, now all the requests are made to the dedicated server. It may help to give solution for your problem.

Comment: So, is not there any way so that apache and mysql can be kept on my machine and can made jqury request from another pc of same network?

Comment: i think there is no option. any way once check with giving the absolute path of the pageB when you click in the pageA. if it not works then u hv to split your application accordingly

Comment: I did it previously (absolute path), but no success :(